# DAX Lookupvalue using Earlier

Tags: powerpivot, dax

As so often, DAX is driving me crazy:
I have a table with client data, including CLIENT ID.
I have another table with client data, including CLIENT ID and NAME.

So, both tables contain CLIENT ID but crucially, in neither table are the CLIENT IDs unique, i.e. there are always multiple instances of the same CLIENT ID but in table 2, all duplicates do have the same NAME associated with them, so it doesn't matter which instance a look-up picks up because the result (NAME) will be the same.

What I want is to go through every single row in table 1, take the CLIENT ID and get the NAME from table two. Simple as that.

I'm trying something like this but it's probably nowhere close:

```
=LOOKUPVALUE(Table2[NAME],Table2[CLIENT ID],EARLIER(Table1[CLIENT ID]))
```

The usual "EARLIER refers to a row context" error appears.

I'm grateful for any help.

Thanks!

Tony

Comment: Note that if multiple rows match the search values, if result_column has diiferent values an error will be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `EARLIER` function in  this case. Just create a new column using this expression:

```
LookupName = 
  LOOKUPVALUE(ClienteTableB[Name],[ClienteID],ClientTableA[ClientID]
  )
```

Note in my example, `ClientTableA` is the table you want to add the name column.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I clearly need to brush up on my Lookupvalue